# showing context menu in contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, contenteditable

I have a contentEditable div with following text for example:

```
<div contentEditable='true'> This document is classified</div>
```

Now for example if user clicks on 'm' in word document I want to show a context menu containing few text choices. That context menu will be contained in a div element. I want to replace the word "document" with the option(text) selected by user from context menu. In my view I have to find absolute position of click to show context menu and then I have to find space elements before and after the caret position and then replace the selection with option selected from context menu. Any idea how I can do it using JavaScript and jQuery?
**Edit:** 
one part of my question is about context menu and other the more important is how i can detect the word on wchich user has clicked on in contentEditable div or in text area on the other hand. my goal is something like in below picture
[image]
actually i want to make a similar transliteration application. the process of script conversion from roman to Urdu has been done however i m facing lot of problems in user interface development on the web. google transliteration application can be found [here](http://www.google.com/transliterate/urdu). i hope someone can help me in getting word under user's mouse and display a context menu containing few choices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to have a look at some of the existing context menu plugins

1. http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/
2. **http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/contextMenu/demo/**
3. http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/context-menu

To get the currently selected word in a text area, have a look at the [fieldSelection](http://laboratorium.0xab.cd/jquery/fieldselection/0.1.0/test.html) plugin.

So using the second plugin and fieldSelection (Disclaimer: I think the indexing regarding string replacement is slightly off - have not fully tested)

**Javascript**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    //replace
    $("#tx").contextMenu({
       menu: 'replace'
    }, function (action, el, pos) {
        update(action, el)
    });

    function update(action, el) {
        var range = $("#tx").getSelection();
        var textLength = $("#tx").val().length;

        var firstPart = $("#tx").val().substring(0, range.start);
        var secondPart = $("#tx").val().substring(range.start, textLength);

        var lastIndexofSpaceInfirstPart = firstPart.lastIndexOf(" ");
        var firstIndexofSpaceInSecondPart = secondPart.indexOf(" ");

        var startOfWord = 0
        var endOfWord = 0


        if (lastIndexofSpaceInfirstPart < 0) {
            // start of string
            startOfWord = 0;
        } else {
            startOfWord = lastIndexofSpaceInfirstPart;
        }

        if (firstIndexofSpaceInSecondPart < 0) {
            // end of textArea
            endOfWord = textLength
        } else {
            endOfWord = firstIndexofSpaceInSecondPart + range.start;
        }

        var word = $.trim($("#tx").val().substring(startOfWord, endOfWord));

        var replaceMent = $("#tx").val().substr(0, startOfWord)
                            + action.toString()
                            + $("#tx").val().substr(endOfWord, textLength);

                alert(
                      "rangeStart: " + range.start +
                      "\n\nrangeEnd: " + range.end +
                      "\n\nrangeLength: " + range.length +
                    +"\n\nfirstPart: " + firstPart
                    + "\n\n secondPart: " + secondPart
                    + "\n\n lastIndexofSpaceInfirstPart: " + lastIndexofSpaceInfirstPart
                    + "\n\n firstIndexofSpaceInSecondPart:" + firstIndexofSpaceInSecondPart
                     + "\n\nWordStart: " + startOfWord
                     + "\n\nEndofWord: " + endOfWord
                     + "\n\nWord: '" + word + "'"
                     + "\n\nNew Text: '" + replaceMent + "'"
                    );
            }
        });
```

**Html**

```
<textarea id="tx">
    Some text
    </textarea>


    <ul id="replace" class="contextMenu">
      <li class="edit"><a href="#youwordhere1">youwordhere1</a></li>
      <li class="cut separator"><a href="#youwordhere2">youwordhere2</a></li>
      <li class="copy"><a href="#youwordhere3">youwordhere3</a></li>
      <li class="paste"><a href="#youwordhere4">youwordhere4</a></li>
      <li class="delete"><a href="#youwordhere5">youwordhere5</a></li>
      <li class="quit separator"><a href="#youwordhere6">youwordhere6</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: @ahmed thank u very much for ur response. i edited the question to clarify the problem a touch more. plz c if u can help me get there

Comment: @muhammed - thats exactly what the above code does. It gets the current word that is under the mouse cursor.

Comment: @muhammed - with regards to the choice of word that appear in the context menu, i guess that will probably need to be updated via ajax before the context menu is rendered.

Comment: @ahmed i have tested this code and it fulfills my requirements to some extent except few problems. 1- context menu appears under browser's context menu in IE. its doing the same in FF for texarea (for div its correct). i have to first left click on the word to get caret there and then right click to make "update" function work properly because getSelection depends upon caret position rather than mouse position. one additional problem is that i m unable to attach keypress event to contenteditable that i will put in seperate question and give u the url. thanks

Comment: @ahmed plz have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112583/rich-text-box-with-content-editablediv thanks

Comment: @ahmed - correct, you need to have the caret on the word to get the context menu. I am not sure if you can do this using the right-mouse click - bearing in mind that although you can get a the mouse click position, I don't know how that would translate to the specific word that's under the mouse pointer. I must admit I tested this with Chrome so I can't comment on IE and FF behaviour. You did say though, when a user clicks 'm'

Comment: hmm i will then turn on the context menu from right click to left click

Comment: @muhammed - i tested this in FF and IE and it works as expected. There is no browser context menu that appears for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. To detect a word under the mouse cursor rock solid reliable: Just wrap every word you want to detect in a separate container, span for example. It is not difficult to do with javascript. Just parse the words in a loop and create span element for every one, then set its innerHTML = word. Then you can read the click event target and it will give you the span with the word.
2. To show a context menu on the spot is a trivial task:
   Create a div with your content menu and make it positiion:absolute and display:none. When you want to show it, set its top and left styles (for example) equal to the target span element offset from the parent container and make its style display = "box". You are all set ;)

Comment: if we wrap the word in span wouldn't it create problem if we want to replace the word. for example it will insert span tag inside the text editor

Comment: It depends on what your editor is. If you want to use some standard text area, then yes, the span tags will show and worse they will have no effect as the browser will interpret them as plain text. But for your div contentEditable='true' I guess you will not have this problem, it supports rich text. Just try it and tell me, it would be interesting to know.